# Set Row and Column definitions by amount of elements

Tags: algorithm, xaml

I want to create my xaml Grid element from the amount of elements

i.e. if I have 6 elements I'll have to do 3 columns and 2 rows (or vice versa)

But my amount of elements (input) can be any value, can be 7, 8, 19, etc.

How can I determinate how many columns and rows I need?

EDIT: More information:
I want my grid as square as possible, doesn't matter the possible empty spots

Comment: what constitutes an acceptable grid size? For example, we can just create a 7x1 for a 7 element, 8x1 for an 8 element..etcetc but i'm sure that's not what you want. how many rows/columns do you want for a 7, 8, 19 element set and why?

Comment: @Calpis as square as possible

Comment: so for a 23 element set, would you want 6x4 or 5x5? 5x5 is square but has 2 empty spots where as 6x4 has only 1 empty spot.

Comment: @Calpis the empty spots doesn't matter as long as the result is the most square possible

Comment: wait so..im confused. in your example you said 6 elements you would want to do a 3x2 but from your last comment, wouldn't a 3x3 work better if empty slots doesn't matter?

Comment: @Calpis yes, but not that much empty slots, with a 3x3 I'll have 3 empty slots.... I think I had to specify I want to minimize the amount of empty places :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Math.Sqrt`:

```
int nElements = 6;
int nColumns = (int)Math.Ceiling(Math.Sqrt(nElements));
int nRows;
if (nElements <= nColumns*(nColumns-1)) // last row remains empty
    nRows = nColumns-1;                 // eliminate it
else
    nRows = nColumns;
```

You can try it with any value of `nElements`. It will do fine! :)